# Java image/tile from file

Tags: java, image, file, icons

Simple question, how to get better resoliution picture from file than icon.
Also would be nice if I could add it on Jlabel. My OS win7.

Now Im using this to get icon, but it gives 16 x 16 icon. Also when I scale it, icon looks terrible and pixeled.

```
tempFile = "shortcuts/testdoc.docx";
ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon) FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(tempFile);
```

Now what I getting
[image: Now what I getting]

What I want to get
[image: What I want to get]

Comment: Have you set the PLAF to the native PLAF?  That often produces better icons.  E.G. see the [File browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).

Comment: Can you say what PLAF stands for? Im first time seeing it.

Comment: Java+PLAF in your favorite search engine should lead you directly to it.  And for future reference, doing that is probably faster than asking me as well.